# Spark benchmark setup

Tags: apache-spark, benchmarking

I would like to do a benchmark on Spark which consists in:

Have 10TB of uncompressed data where each line is at this format: float;float;string.

The job will basically do :

- map on lines to split
- filter on the string
- reduceByKey where key is based on the two floats.
- store result in HDFS

Question are : 
 - how much disk space should I have
 - how much memory
 - what are the parameters for the job (#exec, #core, #mem) and for yarn-site.conf

Currently I have 15To of storage on 10 nodes (16Cores, 16GB, 1.5To of storage) and it fails like :

> ERROR client.TransportClient: Failed to send RPC 6631382768729976966 to benchophadoopslaves1/A.B.C.D:43365: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>   17/07/06 17:05:42
>
> WARN netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(41,[Lscala.Tuple2;@4f4d418,BlockManagerId(41, benchophadoopslaves1, 34521))] in 3 attempts
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 6631382768729976966 to benchophadoopslaves1/A.B.C.D:43365: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>           at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:239)
>           at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$3.operationComplete(TransportClient.java:226)
>           at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:680)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend gave me an hint: give 10GB to the driver. And it works